# How do I change the return type of mergesort to int?

Tags: c++

This is the original code:

```
void mergeSort(int a[], int l, int r) {
    if (r <= l) return;
    int m = (r + l) / 2;
    mergeSort(a, l, m);
    mergeSort(a, m + 1, r);
    merge(a, l, m, r);
}

void merge(int a[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int i, j;
    static int aux[maxN];
    for (i = m + 1; i > l; i--) aux[i - 1] = a[i - 1];
    for (j = m; j < r; j++) aux[r + m - j] = a[j + 1];
    for (int k = l; k <= r; k++) {
        // INCREMENT COUNTER AT THIS STEP
        if (aux[j] < aux[i]) a[k] = aux[j--];
        else a[k] = aux[i++];
    }   
}
```

I need to count the number of variable comparisons made in this code. I have commented in caps where this needs to be done (in the merge function). This being a trick question, we're not allowed to use any global variables as counters. We can only modify the return type and arguments of the functions.

Basically, we need to increment a counter inside the merge function and the mergeSort method needs to return an int (the counter value) instead of void. How can I do it?

Comment: seems like an assignment to me.

Comment: A global variable can be useful!

Comment: Then make a local variable in `merge` initialize it to 0, increment it and return it from `merge`. In mergeSort create a second local variable initialized to zero to add all the values from the calls to `mergeSort` and `merge` and return that value.

Comment: Not really. Always wondered how to manipulate the return types of recursive functions.

Comment: So what's the problem? Incrementing the counter? Returning it from `merge`? Or combining the three counter values to give the value to return from `mergeSort`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I can make the merge function return count but how to return from mergeSort?

Comment: Change the return type to `int` and add the words `return count;` to the end.  It's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

```
int mergeSort(int a[], int l, int r) {
    if (r <= l) return 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    ...
    cnt += mergeSort(a, l, m);
    cnt += mergeSort(a, m + 1, r);
    cnt += merge(a, l, m, r);
    return cnt;
}

int merge(int a[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int cnt = 0;        
    ...
    for (int k = l; k <= r; k++) {
    // INCREMENT COUNTER AT THIS STEP
    // increment cnt here
    }
    return cnt;    
}
```

Comment: All perfect except one thing. How to modify the base condition for recursion. I mean, what should it return now?

Comment: @MattMilna: How many comparisons were done in that case? That's the value it should return.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** You have two functions right now:

```
void mergeSort(int a[], int l, int r);
void merge(int a[], int l, int m, int r);
^^^^
```

Now instead of just sorting `a` (which is logically `void`), you probably want to additionally... return... the number of comparisons. What would you need to do to return that?

Comment: I  want the mergeSort to return the int though. ?\

Comment: I don't know how to do it Barry. :( I can make the merge function return the int but how to make the mergesort return it? It

Comment: I mean, it's a recursive function and how do I modify the base condition?

Comment: @MattMilna How many comparisons do you make when sorting a size-0 array?

Comment: I like how you help me find the answer rather than just telling it to me. Thanks man. I love you so much.